# symfony php template extends twig template

Tags: php, symfony, twig

In my php template (**mytemplate.html.php)** I have

```
$view->extend('::base.html.twig');

$view['slots']->start('content');
...
```

I run the site, but I don't see any result except for this code:

```
{% extends app.request.xmlHttpRequest ? '::ajax-layout.html.twig' : '::page-layout.html.twig' %} {% block content %} {{ content|raw }} {% endblock %}
```

This is source of `::base.html.twig`; Why isn't the result parsed ?

Is allowed to extend twig template in php template ? 
I need to push php template but others is twig.

When I comment:

```
//$view->extend('::base.html.twig');
//$view['slots']->start('content');
```

I see the results of php template.

Comment: If your using PHP templates shouldn't they be named ***.html.php?

Comment: i update code - this template have html.php and try extends twig template so base is html.twig

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Twig and PHP templates are not compatible. You can't extend one from the other.